# Finding a path visiting most nodes in complete digraph with cost limit and positive or negative edge weights

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-traversal

I'm leaving out some specifics because this is a challenge problem and I don't want to be spoon-fed the answer, but I need a nudge in the right direction.

I am given a complete digraph with the following characteristics:

- There is one "start" node
- There is one "end" node
- There are N additional "special" nodes
- Edges may have positive or negative weights

It looks something like this (for N = 3):

[image: Example graph]

Starting at the start node, the goal is to determine the maximum number of the "special" nodes I can visit before reaching the end node given a maximum path cost. Any node may be revisited.

N is at most very small number (less than 10), so I was thinking about enumerating all the possible paths and selecting the longest one. This smells NP to me; so then, the question is, is that the case? Is this a variant of a problem I should be aware of as a Computer Scientist? How should I approach this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: It's at least as hard as the NP-hard problem Hamiltonian Path, since an instance of that problem can be turned into an instance of your problem by making every node special.

Comment: Hint: There could be a huge number of paths, but there are "only" about 3.6 million permutations of 10 objects.  (Also: Think of a way to  preprocess to speed up the evaluation of each permutation.)

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I should clarify; the special nodes are distinct from the start and end nodes. Does that change anything? I was looking into Hamiltonian Paths but wasn't sure if they were relevant given that any node can be revisited.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't completely specify the transformation: You would also set the maximum path cost to n-1, and every edge has weight 1.  Then, even though in your problem edges are *allowed* to be traversed more than once, if the goal is to see how many of the n special nodes can be traversed for a cost of at most n-1, the answer will be n if and only if there is a HP.  (Also if start and end nodes cannot be special, then add an additional start and end node, and connect them to every other node by an edge.)

Comment: This is very helpful. I think I have a good idea on how to proceed. Just one last question -- does getting the Hamiltonian paths work when there are negative edge weights? There are cases where the correct answer is reached by exceeding the cost limit and then bringing it down by revisiting a node with a negative cost. I've added an example graph to clarify.

Comment: The Hamiltonian Path problem is already NP-hard for an unweighted graph, so negative edge weights never come into it.  Remember, to show NP-hardness you show how to convert an instance of the already-known-to-be-NP-hard problem into an instance of your problem, not the other way around.